# CheckStyle Java Installation | MIT Software Construction

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, software-design, checkstyle

I am following the eclipse set up from MIT's software construction course[1](http://web.mit.edu/6.031/www/sp21/getting-started/#@paste_into_resource). The installation yields an error and I am not sure how to fix this (pictured below)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojcQg.png). The URL yielding an error returns a 404 error, so I don't know if their site is down or an issue with the package I'm using from MIT. Any advice is appreciated!

[Error Message From Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojcQg.png)

Comment: Why not contact the [course staff](http://web.mit.edu/6.031/www/sp21/general/staff.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am not a student at MIT, just working through their open-courseware material. Not sure it would be appropriate for me to reach out.

Comment: You can try. It is unlikely that we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the update site recently [moved](https://github.com/checkstyle/eclipse-cs/issues/279) to a [new location](https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs-update-site/).

If you don't want to contact the course staff directly, you could raise an issue against [the relevant GitHub project](https://github.com/6031/eclipse031), suggesting they update the setup file.

In the short term, you should be able to download the file to disk, change the URL (look for a line like `<repository url="https://checkstyle.github.io/eclipse-cs/update"/>` and change the URL to `https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs-update-site/`) and use the "Browse File System" button in the Eclipse installer instead of pasting the remote URL.

Comment: Phenomenal advice! For completeness, the response at the old URL (https://checkstyle.github.io/eclipse-cs/update) can be saved and edited as a .setup.txt , then be sure to save it just as a .setup so the eclipse can use it during its setup. The URL only appears once and can be changed to the one mentioned above by rimesc!

Thank you!